pip error "error: externally-managed-environment " while instaling transformers==4.30.2
I was trying to install fooccus ai on arch linux:

python3 -m venv fooocus_env
source fooocus_env/bin/activate

pip install -r requirements_versions.txt

output
(fooocus_env) ➜  Fooocus git:(main) pip install -r requirements_versions.txt
    
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip
.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

(fooocus_env) ➜  Fooocus git:(main) pip install -r requirements_versions.txt
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip
error: subprocess-exited-with-error


× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

What i try to do:
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install pip==21.3.1 (broke my pip, used "python -m ensurepip --upgrade" to repeit it)
python3 -m pip install -r requirements_versions.txt same error
sudo pacman -S python python-pip
tried not using venv or creating new python venv
pip3 install -r requirements_versions.txt
pip3 install -r requirements_versions.txt --pre
tried installing transformers==4.30.2
pip install transformers==4.30.2
pip install transformers==4.30.2  
error: externally-managed-environment
× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try 'pacman -S
   python-xyz', where xyz is the package you are trying to
   install.
   If you wish to install a non-Arch-packaged Python package,
   create a virtual environment using 'python -m venv path/to/venv'.
   Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip.
   If you wish to install a non-Arch packaged Python application,
   it may be easiest to use 'pipx install xyz', which will manage a
   virtual environment for you. Make sure you have python-pipx
   installed via pacman.
note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution
provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing
--break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
yay python-xyz
sudo pacman -S python-pipx
pip install -r requirements.txt --break-system-packages
tried uninstalling python and pip and rust
my system
"Arch Linux
6.9.3-arch1-1
Intel i7-10700K (16) @ 5.100GHz
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060
pip 24.0 (python 3.12)"

The error suggests there is something wrong during the installation process. If it happens to me, I will install dependencies in the requirement file one by one manually. Also, As you use Arch Linux, there is potential conflict between pip and pacman

I tried installing all the dependencies one by one, I installed all of them except  transformers==4.30.2

Please read [mre] and make sure the question walks through a single path with clear steps to reproduce, starting from scratch. Make sure everything is appropriately formatted - read the formatting help and make sure you understand how to format multi-line code blocks.

In particular, telling us that you installed requirements from the requirements_versions.txt file is not helpful, because we can't tell which requirements those are, nor which one failed. The separate attempt not using a venv is taking a step backwards - running into a completely unrelated problem that is preventing it from getting any further. But if it did get further, it would almost certainly encounter the same problem again.
